# Multiple pages in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So I want to have multiple pages in PyQt5; for example, when I click a button it transition to another page. This is my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, 
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        Button = QPushButton("OK")


        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(Button)


        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)    

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')    
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to have it that when I click the button, it transitions to another page, in which there is another button that if I press it will transitions back to the initial page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use as `QStackedWidget` for this, for example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QStackedWidget, QLabel)

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.stacked_widget.currentChanged.connect(self.set_button_state)
        self.next_button.clicked.connect(self.next_page)
        self.prev_button.clicked.connect(self.prev_page)


    def initUI(self):

        self.next_button = QPushButton('Next')
        self.prev_button = QPushButton('Previous')
        self.next_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.prev_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.prev_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.next_button)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)


    def set_button_state(self, index):
        self.prev_button.setEnabled(index > 0)
        n_pages = len(self.stacked_widget)
        self.next_button.setEnabled( index % n_pages < n_pages - 1)

    def insert_page(self, widget, index=-1):
        self.stacked_widget.insertWidget(index, widget)
        self.set_button_state(self.stacked_widget.currentIndex())

    def next_page(self):
        new_index = self.stacked_widget.currentIndex()+1
        if new_index < len(self.stacked_widget):
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(new_index)

    def prev_page(self):
        new_index = self.stacked_widget.currentIndex()-1
        if new_index >= 0:
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(new_index)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    for i in range(5):
        ex.insert_page(QLabel(f'This is page {i+1}'))
    ex.resize(400,300)
    ex.show()
    app.exec()
```

Another option could be to use a `QWizard` which is a rather specialized class designed to generate a dialog with the same look and feel as a setup dialog that many programs use for their installation.

Comment: While a bit more complex to use (but much more complete and extendible), it's worth mentioning the possibility of using [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html).

Comment: I mentioned QWizard at the end of my post.

Comment: sorry, somehow I missed that :-(

Comment: no problem. It's easy to miss after a wall of code ;-)

Comment: Thanks. But how do I create pages that are discrete, not in the same format. Like designing every pages individually, and having a main page to maneuver around.

Comment: @hoolahooping: In my example I just used a `QLabel` for each page that I added via `ex.insert_page`, but that could have been any widget. The only thing that is consistent between the pages are the two buttons at the bottom which are outside the `QStackedWidget`. It is doable to have each page have their own buttons for maneuvering around but that requires a bit more work since you would need to make sure each navigation button on each page sets the `QStackedWidget` to the correct index every time you add a page.